# Which is correct note?

Tags: piano

On measure 22 at 1:30-1:31, she hit an F instead of a D as in the score.  So, which is correct?

It is in this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqpvE45-Cq0) of an arrangement of "Chi Mai" from *Le Professionel* by Ennio Morricone.

[image: "Chi Mai", mm. 22–24, Morricone/Bulakhova]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both and neither is correct, but D is the best choice.**

This is the YouTuber's own arrangement of the original piece. The original piece is a half-step lower, doesn't include arpeggios at this point in the music, and uses a different inversion of the chord (here, D would be the lowest note instead of G). So in that sense, the whole thing is wrong — if the goal were to most accurately reproduce the original.

This being an arrangement, however, it's clear the arranger's goal was to give the sense of the original without being slavish to it. At that level, both D and F are fine to play, because both are part of the underlying chord. So at that level, the arranger can play either one — it's not at all unusual for a performer of their own arrangement to make changes on the fly.

But since she wrote D and played F, clearly one is what was intended and one is not, but short of writing to the arranger to ask, there's no way to know which is "correct".

The best choice, however, is to play the D. The F is already in the melody, so the D fills out the chord and avoids doubling a dissonant pitch. The D is also a prominent pitch in the original (the bass note), so there's a good case to be made there as well that it should be present in the arpeggio.